# git merge feature branch to master branch after squashing commits

Tags: git

I have a feature branch with several commit messages, and the commit messages were squashed into a single commit when merging with the master branch. Now, I have made another change in the feature branch, and when I try to merge with the master branch, due to differences in the history, I can see all the changes and commits that were squashed.

How can I merge the feature branch with the master branch while preserving the squashed commits?

Comment: You should not continue working on a feature branch after squashing it during a merge, since git doesn't consider that branch as merged. As such, when you keep working on it, and try to merge again, git will ask you to bring along all the changes from the feature branch *again*, which will now be in conflict with the target branch due to the squash commit there. Instead, either create a new branch from your main branch after such a squash, or reset your feature branch to your main branch after such a squash, to "clean up" the history of it.

Comment: Control question: How exactly do you want to merge your new work with the main? Do you want your new work to be "on top of" the main branch, in the same manner as the squashed commit from earlier? Or would you be happy with an actual merge, you just don't want the duplicate history that was squashed?

Comment: "and the commit messages were squashed into a single commit when merging with the master branch" No. A squash merge, despite its name, is not a merge. The feature branch was _never_ merged into the master branch. That's the problem. You might want to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/

Comment: I ended up creating a local feature branch, pulled develop, and pushed to the remote feature branch.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen What do you mean by "reset" and "clean up" the feature branch?

Comment: By "reset" I mean that you do the equivalent of `git reset --hard main` on your feature branch, this will point your branch pointer to the same commit as you have at the tip of main, and thus it will "start fresh" from main again. You should not keep working on the old branch, since you didn't do an actual merge then git does not understand that the work on that branch is actually already on main, and it will keep trying to remind you or merge those changes into main... again.

Answer (score 0):

If I undertand you correctly you can achive what you want using merge with `--no-ff` key but not `--squash`
This will allow you to have following structure

[image: Project structure]

The commits B, C and D will preserve even if you delete your feature branch.